# TikZ is printing the coordinate location and not the actual point. What am I missing?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was trying to draw a picture of a triangle.  Adjacent to the triangle is supposed to be a line with points along it whose distances from the top end point are the lengths of the sides of the triangle.  But I'm unable to draw the line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
 Verify that the following triangle has been constructed per the
 specificiations.

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,inner sep=2pt,fill}]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (0,3in);  

  %\draw (A) circle (3.5in);
  %\draw (B) circle (4in);
  \tkzInterCC[R](A,2.5in)(B,4.5in) \tkzGetPoints{C}{D}
  \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

  \node at (A) {};
  \node at (B) {};
  \node at (C) {};

  \node[fill=none] at ($(A)+(-90:2ex)$) {$C$};
  \node[fill=none] at ($(B)+(+90:2ex)$) {$B$};
  \node[fill=none] at ($(C)+(-90:2ex)$) {$A$};

  \coordinate (D) at (2in,3in);

  \path let \p1=(A),
            \p2=(B),
            \p3=(C)
        in
        coordinate (E) at  ($(D)-(0,{veclen(\p1,\p2)})$)
        coordinate (F) at  ($(D)-(0,{veclen(\p1,\p3)})$);

  \node at (D) {};
  \node at (E) {};
  \node at (F) {};
  \draw (D) -- (F) -- (E);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

veclen expects numbers but you are supplying coordinates. So changing the relevant lines with

```
    coordinate (E) at  ($(D)-(0,{veclen(\x1-\x2,\y1-\y2)})$)
    coordinate (F) at  ($(D)-(0,{veclen(\x1-\x3,\y1-\y3)})$);
```

draws something but I don't know if that was the intended computation.

instead using

```
\path let \p1=($(A)-(B)$),
          \p2=($(A)-(C)$)
```

and using `veclen(\x1,\y1)` and `veclen(\x2,\y2)` would make the computations less susceptible to such mistakes.